# Regex to match certain characters anywhere between two characters

Tags: regex

I want to detect (and return) any punctuation within brackets. The line of text I'm looking at will have multiple sets of brackets (which I can assume are properly formatted). So given something like this:

```
[abc.] [!bc]. [.e.g] [hi]
```

I'd want to detect all those cases and return something like `[[.], [!], [..]]`.

I tried to do `/{.*?([.,!?]+).*?}/g` but then it returns true for `[hello], [hi]` which I don't want to match!

I'm using JS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match substrings between square brackets and then remove all chars that are not punctuation:

```js
const text = '[abc.] [!bc]. [.e.g]';
const matches = text.match(/\[([^\][]*)]/g).map(x => `[${x.replace(/[^.,?!]/g, '')}]`)
console.log(matches);
```

If you need to make your regex fully Unicode aware you can leverage ECMAScript 2018+ compliant solution like

```js
const text = '[abc.] [!bc、]. [.e.g]';
const matches = text.match(/\[([^\][]*)]/g).map(x => `[${x.replace(/[^\p{P}\p{S}]/gu, '')}]`)
console.log(matches);
```

So,

- `\[([^\][]*)]` matches a string between `[` and `]` with no other `[` and `]` inside
- `.replace(/[^.,?!]/g, '')` removes all chars other than `.`, `,`, `?` and `!`
- `.replace(/[^\p{P}\p{S}]/gu, '')` removes all chars other than Unicode punctuation proper and symbols.

Comment: Cool, thank you! I only want to return the punctuation for each [] if there is any, not necessarily map each bracketed part to an array containing its punctuation (sorry, that was unclear from my post!). I know I can just filter out the empty arrays, but can I make my regex search for punctuation within the brackets, and then return matching groups if there are any?

Comment: @www You will still have to apply a post-processing step because you cannot match and skip chars at the same time. To avoid matching bracketed substrings without punctuation, use `/\[([^\][.,?!]*[.,?!][^\][]*)]/g` or `/\[([^\][\p{P}\p{S}]*[\p{P}\p{S}][^\][]*)\]/gu` (Unicode-aware)

Comment: Great, thank you! Why I do need to include the punctuation in the first character class that gets negated? i.e. why not `/\[([^\][]*[.,?!][^\][]*)]/g`